# select first option in select when user press cancel in jquery ui Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-select

I am using **Jquery UI**

```
$("#tableDiv select").change(function() {

    var getVal=$(this).val();
    var getText= $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text();

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                //???????????
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            }
        }
    });

});
```

I want to select the first option , if user press cancel. currently selected option still selected when user cancel the operation.

Update me !

Comment: Please post your HTML and if possible, a jsFiddle.

Comment: I have a div named="tableDiv", in which there are many drop-down list, when user select an option from drop-down list; jquery dialog confirmation box apprear. @j08691

Answer (score 0):

try this (edited as suggested):

```
$("#tableDiv select").change(function() {

var getVal=$(this).val();
var getText= $(this[this.selectedIndex]).text();

$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $('#sel'+getVal+' option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
            $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
        }
     }
  }); 
});
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: I have no any drop-down Id

Comment: it is not working! I have add Id attribute in select and solve my problem ! following solution is working `$('#sel'+getVal+' option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");`